# How to detect in Java if SOAP message is MTOM

Tags: java, mtom

Is there any way in Java (1.6) to detect if SOAP message is MTOM or do I need to create method for that to check if message has multiparts?

Based on the SOAP 1.2 specs to

> determine whether the HTTP SOAP Transmission Optimization Feature is
>   used by checking the presence of the application/xop+xml media type

but I don't see it in my MTOM message which in a test (minimalistic) case looks like

```
------=_Part_0_591998098.1543337064443
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

<soapenv:Envelope>some SOAP message</soapenv:Envelope>


------=_Part_0_591998098.1543337064443
Content-Type: null
Content-ID: <1.4a159e8e@apache.org>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/html

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?><html><head><title>testlf</title></head><body><b>Message Type: </b>Direct<br /><b>Subject: </b>testlf<br /><hr /></body></html>

------=_Part_0_591998098.1543337064443
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/635742060149828871>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version='1.0'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl'?>Here is PDF

------=_Part_0_591998098.1543337064443--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up with

```
private boolean isMTOM(SOAPMessage msg) throws SOAPException, IOException
{

    boolean isMTOM = false;

    MimeHeaders headers = msg.getMimeHeaders();
    String[] contentType = headers.getHeader("Content-Type");

    if(contentType[0].toLowerCase().contains("multipart/related") && (contentType[0].toLowerCase().contains("application/soap+xml") || contentType[0].toLowerCase().contains("application/xop+xml"))) {
        isMTOM = true;
    }

    return isMTOM;
}
```